# Android 2.2 development with Adobe Air

Tags: android, air, flashdevelop

I am currently trying to develop an app for Android platforms in FlashDevelop, using Adobe AIR, and for which I would like the minimum target OS to be Android 2.2.
I have no problems running the app on Android 4.0, however when I try to debug the app on Android 2.2 or 2.3 the app crashes.

Do I need to use an earlier AIR version (I am currently using AIR 3.4) to compile my app in order to be able to run on earlier Android versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not necessary, we have developed a similar configuration app for android, and it works on 2.3 on wards, but for 2.2 or earlier, check the [technical specifications](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/tech-specs.html)